# How to remove unwanted 'collapsable region' in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I was copy-pasting xml comment for multiple function. Soon after, many unintended 'collapsable regions' popped up. One example is shown in the image. [image: Unknown toggle]

Why is this happen and how do I remove this unwanted 'collapsable region'? I've tried deleting the line, multiple lines, but no luck until now.

P.S. AFAIK, collapsable region is a respond to bracket pair [ '{...}' ] or a region pair [#region #endregion].
P.S. what I code is in C# language

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay, just find a roundway. Moving the whole code to notepad then removing back does remove the unwanted 'collapsable region'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).